# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, mediatek

I am having problems with my Wi-Fi connection. I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Asus TP500LA, and in the Wi-Fi setting it says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found"

Can someone please help me figure out this Wi-Fi dilemma. Thank You in advance!

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e074]
```

Comment: @SiddharthDushantha Why would installing Broadcom drivers solve OP's issue with Mediatek device?!

Comment: My wireless is working now. Thank you so much! The link pomsky sent worked!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to tick the option to install the WiFi hardware. [image: option to install WiFi hardware]

I know that there is way to fix by installing the WiFi drivers. But I have forgotten what the package it was. If I were you, I would check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/782646).

If you have tried everything you can, I would recommend you reinstall Ubuntu and make sure to tick the option to install the WiFi hardwares.

Comment: I just reinstalled Ubuntu and made sure to tick the option to install the Wi-Fi hardware, but I'm not seeing any results